# changing ID of form input element in django when it's created

Tags: python, django, forms, input

When django creates a form the id for the input are the following:

```
<input id="id_name"..../>
```

How do I change the id to let's say "test"?

Has to be somehow in the form.py, right?

```
class ReviewForm (forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location']=forms.CharField(label='', required=False)
        self.fields['review']=forms.CharField(label='', required=False)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you instantiate your form, you'll want to call it with the `auto_id` keyword set to a string with the format character '%s' which will be replaced by the field name.

So you'll want to do this:

`ReviewForm(auto_id="test_%s")`

And your ids will be generated with `test_` as a prefix, followed by the field name.

Direct from the Django 1.8 docs:

> Use the auto_id argument to the Form constructor to control the id and label behavior.
>
> ...
>
> If auto_id is set to a string containing the format character '%s', then the form output will include  tags, and will generate id attributes based on the format string. For example, for a format string 'field_%s', a field named subject will get the id value 'field_subject'.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags

Comment: A really noob question, where do I instantiate the form ?

Comment: You instantiate it in your view. I would recommend giving the Django documentation a good read. Here's the introduction to Forms:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: It works for me like this: `ReviewForm(auto_id=False)`

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do this, explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/)

```
[class ReviewForm (forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields\['location'\]=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'myField'}),label='', required=False)
        self.fields\['review'\]=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'myField'}),label='', required=False)
```